# Disable register button Redmine

Tags: button, registration, redmine

Is it possible to remove register button in code in Redmine, I know that I can disable in admin panel, but I need remove it in code. I used helm install to install Redmine

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here and why is it it not enough to set the setting appropriately? The appropriate response to your question depends on those details as this looks like an [XY-Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Please edit your question and explain in more detail what exactly you are trying to achieve (and why).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete below code from **lib/redmine.rb**

Find the:

```
Redmine::MenuManager.map :account_menu do |menu|
  menu.push :login, :signin_path, :if => Proc.new {!User.current.logged?}
  menu.push :register, :register_path,
            :if => Proc.new {!User.current.logged? && Setting.self_registration?}
```

and delete or comment following two lines:

```
  menu.push :register, :register_path,
            :if => Proc.new {!User.current.logged? && Setting.self_registration?}
```

After that restart Redmine...